# Edge completion using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am new to image processing using opencv and my main goal is to complete the open intersecting contours after using canny edge detection for images of soil samples as I want to segment the soil particles and detect the area of the particles in pixels from the images ... I have already written a code that takes a point as an input and emit rays in all directions and detect the distances to the curve around it and can close the shape but I don't know how to use it to complete the contours in that image automatically so that all open contours are closed..

**Image**
[image: image 1]

this is the result after performing edge detection and using bilateral filter for smoothing images : 
 [image]

Comment: can you add some code and outputs which you are getting so that we can help you better

Comment: You should try out if you can close the gaps with  a [closing operation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [closing operation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html#closing) would work fairly well in closing most of the gaps in your picture:

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(6,6))
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
```

For a kernel of size 2 you will get:

[image]

By increasing the kernel size, you will be able to fill bigger gaps. At some point, you will inevitably lose information about the background though, since bigger gaps in between foreground objects which may include partially concealed background objects will be closed as well. E.g for a kernel size of 6 you will get:

[image]

You could experiment with different kernel sizes and forms and see which will produce the best results for your application.